# Can we relate Latency and Throughput with parallelism

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, parallel-processing

I found lots of blogs and answers to Latency vs Throughput. But none of them relate it with parallelism.
I wonder why can't we relate them as follows,

**If throughput is larger when compared to latency then there should be parallelism involved**.  (***assuming nil optimization while batching***)

eg. 10ms latency and 1000 tps mean there is an increase in tps (because 10ms latency mean 100tps) then there is a huge chance of the involvement of multi-threading or parallelism may be in the CPU level. If there is no optimization   while multiple transactions are batched.

Also,
What are the factors which increases throughput over latency.?

Comment: I think you can't simplify it like that, as there might be data that can't be parallelized where all the parallel pipes depend on.

Comment: I agree with you. I think there were some clarity problems in my question so I removed the equation and updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: there may be many advantages to batching (increase throughput at the expense of latency) that are not related to parallelism. Sometimes there are fixed unit costs; sometimes a more global optimization may have a big effect; sometimes duplicates can be found and discarded etc. etc..

That a 747 full of hard drives is probably the highest-throughput way to send data across the world has little to do with parallelism.

Comment: Correct up voted, as I mentioned in my question optimization is there definitely (added more clarity in question).
But in current situation 3rd party vendors says they have 3ms latency and 1 million tps for their product (may be some in-memory DB, queues etc..). That is what confuses me. They argue with an example of 3 node cluster. In such cases there may be 10-20 cores and 20-50 GB of RAM and latency talks about a single transaction here they hide the fact  that parallelism is a major part when we talk about TPS.

Answer (score 0):

Latency is a purely a unit of time and throughput (which is the amount of work done per unit time) is partly related to time.

In a single threaded environment, you can think of these two being inversely related, i.e. higher the latency, lower the throughput etc.

Think of parallelism as another dimension to this matrix. When possible ([Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)), parallelism will increase the throughput, up to a certain limit. However this can be affected by the latency of the units in the system. For example, imagine a single threaded system operating at 2GHz and a 4 component parallel system operating at 300 MHz. For the simplicity assume the application is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). In this case single threaded one will outperform the parallel one. Now if we increase the operating speed of parallel units to 501 MHz, they will outperform the single threaded one.

Comment: Ok I have updated the question because of some clarity problems. My question is, What are the factors which increases throughput when compared to latency.